Azure function app 4.XX disabling the proxy's, What are the alternatives creating the proxies for Analysis servers
We have created the proxies in the function app to connect to the analysis services but now the azure function app 4.x is not supporting the proxies.  Now what the best alternative to work on the proxies for the analysis service.
Note: if we update 4.xx version then Proxies got disabled.
I had updated 4.xx version but Proxies got disabled.
I am looking for alternative solution

According to this SO answer by @Dinhduy and @Juilian Huppauff and this MS Document
You will need to add App setitngs in your Function app like below to enable Proxy:-
AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags:EnableProxies



Or you can implement the proxy and call analysis service in your Function code itself by using Analysis service client sdk.
And you will have to enable proxy via Azure APIM service infront of your Function app service to act as a proxy as suggested in the Document. APIM supports Function App integration that can act as a Proxy.


Now what the best alternative to work on the proxies for the analysis service.

You will need to add App setitngs in your Function app like below to enable Proxy:-
AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags:EnableProxies


Or you can implement the proxy and call analysis service in your Function code itself by using Analysis service client sdk.
And you will have to enable proxy via Azure APIM service infront of your Function app service to act as a proxy. APIM supports Function App integration that can act as a Proxy.


Above method will only work for Http Trigger Function if you want to call any other Function you can call it directly like below:-

References:-
SO answer by @Dinhduy and @Juilian Huppauff
MS Document
